Packets sent to tun Interface not received by Application

i have been stuck at this problem for quite some time and just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
What I am trying to achieve is to intercept packets (IP and TCP), change their header and then send them onward to their original destination.
My current setup is the following:
I have a TUN Interface (named tun_in) and my wifi-card (named wlp0s20f3) set up with the following configuration
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether --:--:--:--:--:-- brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.69/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 852237sec preferred_lft 852237sec
    inet6 ----:----:----:--:----:----:----:----/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6726sec preferred_lft 3126sec
    inet6 ----::----:----:----:----/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
27: tun_in: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.178.69/24 scope global tun_in
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I also have a Program which (using libpnet (a rust library for low-level networking https://github.com/libpnet/libpnet)) listens for all incoming packets on the TUN Interface and forwards them to my wifi-card. The program also sends all ICMP packets (that are incoming on my wifi-card) back to the TUN interface. 
So it is kind of acts like a bridge (e.g. TUN -> wlp and wlp -> TUN). 
This also kinda works (e.g. in Wireshark all expected packets are present)
Wireshark output capturing on the tun_ininterface
Wireshark output capturing on the any interface
(The duplicates are once on the wlp-interface and once on the tun_in-interface (according to my understanding))
So based on this we can see, that the packets traverse the network correctly. The problem is that the ping command i use (ping 8.8.8.8 -4 -I tun_in) doesn't see any incoming packets. This means that the packets have to be dropped somewhere in the kernel (right?) (because they are seen by Wireshark but not by ping).
I used dropwatch to inspect that and it told me
39 drops at tun_net_xmit+2df (0xffffffffc1735d7f) [software]
94 drops at icmp_rcv+1fb (0xffffffffb9eaa6eb) [software]
37 drops at tun_net_xmit+2df (0xffffffffc1735d7f) [software]
7 drops at unix_stream_connect+344 (0xffffffffb9f14764) [software]
113 drops at tun_net_xmit+2df (0xffffffffc1735d7f) [software]
87 drops at tun_net_xmit+2df (0xffffffffc1735d7f) [software]
93 drops at tun_net_xmit+2df (0xffffffffc1735d7f) [software]
93 drops at icmp_rcv+1fb (0xffffffffb9eaa6eb) [software]
12 drops at tun_net_xmit+2df (0xffffffffc1735d7f) [software]

That may explain why the application (ping) doesn't see the the responses, but I don't know why the packets get dropped (and I also don't know what I can do with the information that the packets get dropped at icmp_rcv and icmp_rcv).
Another thing I am not quite sure about is: When my application opens the tun-interface and writes to it. Are these packets treated like they are incoming (e.g. as if they came from "the wire") or are they outgoing (which would be another possible explanation as to why the ping command bound to the interface tun_in doesn't see the packets)?
If anybody could provide some help, that would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.
